# How do I print 4 numbers in each row in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, while-loop

How do I print 4 numbers in a row? I am a complete beginner. This is Python code I did for Fibonacci sequence.

For example, if I put 6 as an input, I get

```
0 1 1 2 3 5
```

However, I want to get it like

```
0 1 1 2
3 5
```

Code:

```
i = 1
n1 = 0
n2 = 1
seq = n1 + n2
num = int(input("Enter a positive number: "))

while i <= num:
    print(n1, end = " ")
    n1 = n2
    n2 = seq
    seq = n1 + n2
    i += 1
print()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    print(n1, end = " " if i % 4 else "\n")
```

Comment: OMG thank you so much for the quick answer! I don't know why I thought it would be way more complicated than that! haha Thanks again.